# Need logic for iterating over a list in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I've a list which is

```
List < TempVO> lstTemp = new ArrayList < TempVO> ();
```

`TempVO` is a class containing

```
zoneId,tempId and tempValue
```

now the list will have entries like mentioned below

```
zoneId tempId tempValue
-----------------------
 2 /     1    /  check    
 2   /    3     /check  
 2    /   4   /  check  
 2     /  4   /  entered1  
 3    /   5   /  check  
 3     /  8    / primary  
 3    /   6  /   check  
 3   /    8   /  check
```

My requirement is to remove that entries with `tempValue= check` from the list where if it has 2 entries for the same `zoneId` and `tempId`
(i,e) my new list should contain

```
zoneId tempId tempValue
-----------------------
 2 /     1    /  check    
 2   /    3     /check    
 2     /  4   /  entered1  
 3    /   5   /  check  
 3     /  8    / primary  
 3    /   6  /   check
```

How do i do this?

Comment: As stated, the question appears to have no wider application than solving your given problem. Could you rephrase it so it becomes more useful to a wider audience?

Comment: suppose you have **tempValue=primary** in your arrayList. then should the same check apply to it also or you need for **tempValue=check** only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote something up for you. I implemented the class TempVO and iterated over a list of those in a main function(my programs entry point) using a nested loop. I check for every TempVO if the tempValue is "check". If so, I check if there is another TempVO in the list with the same zoneId and tempId. If so, I don't print the TempVO. You can follow it in my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
class TempVO {
    private int zoneId;
    private int tempId;
    private String tempValue;
    public TempVO(int zoneId, int tempId, String tempValue) {
        super();
        this.zoneId = zoneId;
        this.tempId = tempId;
        this.tempValue = tempValue;
    }
    public int getZoneId() {
        return zoneId;
    }
    public void setZoneId(int zoneId) {
        this.zoneId = zoneId;
    }
    public int getTempId() {
        return tempId;
    }
    public void setTempId(int tempId) {
        this.tempId = tempId;
    }
    public String getTempValue() {
        return tempValue;
    }
    public void setTempValue(String tempValue) {
        this.tempValue = tempValue;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "zonedId: " + this.zoneId + " | tempId: " + this.tempId + " | tempValue: " + this.tempValue;
    }
}
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // initialize list
        List<TempVO> tempVOs = new ArrayList<>();
        tempVOs.add(new TempVO(2, 1, "check"));
        tempVOs.add(new TempVO(2, 3, "check"));
        tempVOs.add(new TempVO(2, 4, "check"));
        tempVOs.add(new TempVO(2, 4, "enterd1"));
        tempVOs.add(new TempVO(3, 5, "check"));
        tempVOs.add(new TempVO(3, 8, "primary"));
        tempVOs.add(new TempVO(3, 6, "check"));
        tempVOs.add(new TempVO(3, 8, "check"));
        // only print values wherein interested
        for(int i = 0; i < tempVOs.size(); i++) {
            TempVO outerTempVO = tempVOs.get(i);
            boolean keep = true;
            if("check".equals(outerTempVO.getTempValue())) {
                for(int j = 0; j < tempVOs.size(); j++) {
                    if(i != j) {
                        TempVO innerTempVO = tempVOs.get(j);
                        if(outerTempVO.getTempId() == innerTempVO.getTempId() && outerTempVO.getZoneId() == innerTempVO.getZoneId()) {
                            keep = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(keep)
                System.out.println(outerTempVO);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement a `equals()` method in `TempVO`.

Then use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of `List`.

```java
public class TempVO {
    private int zoneId;
    private int tempId;
    private String tempValue;

    // getters & setters

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        TempVO t = (TempVO) obj;
        if (zoneId != t.zoneId) {
            return false;
        }
        if (tempId != t.tempId) {
            return false;
        }
        if (tempValue == null) {
            return t.tempValue == null
        }
        return tempValue.equals(t.tempValue);
    }
}

Set<TempVO> tempSet = new HashSet<TempVO>();
// now add to the set; the set will automatically remove duplicates
tempSet.add(myTemp);
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a newbie to java..Could you please elaborate this?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing  equals and set is one solution.

If you want just another arraylist, use this:

```
List < TempVO> lstTemp = new ArrayList < TempVO> ();
List < TempVO> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList < TempVO> ();
for(TempVO temp : lstTemp) {
    if(condition) {
         toBeRemoved.add(temp);
    }
}
lstTemp.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is, that `condition` is *ugly* to implement. It would be something like `lstTemp.contains(temp)`. This, however is already done in `Set`, and much more performant there. Therefore, although the TO asked about `List`, I wouldn't use `List` for such a case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper class as follows

```
class ZoneTempHelper{
  private long zoneId;
  private long tempId;
  //implement equals() & hashCode() + accessor

}
```

now iterate through list, to group the entries by `tempId`,`zoneId` to `tempValues`

```
Map<ZoneTempHelper, List<String>> map = new HashMap<ZoneTempHelper, List<String>>();
for(TempVO tempVO: list){
   ZomeTempHelper helper = new ZoneTempHelper(tempVo.getTempID(), tempVO.getZoneId());
   List<String> tempValues = map.get(helper);
   if(tempValues == null){
        tempValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        map.put(helper, tempValues);
   }
   tempValues.add(tempVo.getTempVAlue());

}
```

Now iterate through `Map` to check if there are more than one entry for same `tempId` & `zoneId` with value `check`, if so remove from `list`

```
for(ZoneTempHelper helper: map.keySet()){
   List<String> values = map.get(helper);
   if(values.size() == 2 && values .contains("check")){ 
      list.remove(new TempVo(helper.getTempId(), helper.getZoneId(), "check"))
   }
}
```

Make sure you implement proper `hashcode()` & `equals()` in `TempVo`